# How do I delete an entry in 'ip route list'?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I'm having problems working out the correct command to delete the third line from this `ip route list`:

```
#ip route list
default via 172.31.16.1 dev eth0  metric 100 
172.31.16.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.18.50 
172.31.16.0/20 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.23.44 #REMOVE ME
172.32.23.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.32.23.44
```

Comment: But, how did it end up there?  Are you using dhcp on `eth0` and `eth1` or `/e/n/interfaces`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command to do that would be:

```
ip route del 172.31.16.0/20 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.23.44
```

Comment: thanks, can be checked also with sudo route, and using also the via clause `sudo ip route delete default via 182.18.1.1 dev tun0`

Answer (score 2):

I would try:

```
ip route del ROUTE
```

Link to [man ip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/ip.8.html)